# What does Rails.cache.fetch *.to_s do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
if Rails.cache
  Rails.cache.fetch(20.to_s) # ec2-50-17-225-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
  Rails.cache.fetch(0.to_s)  # ec2-174-129-33-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
  Rails.cache.fetch(10.to_s) # ec2-174-129-16-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
  Rails.cache.fetch(30.to_s) # ec2-54-242-2-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
end
```

I'm not entirely sure what this code does. Is it setting cache variables? Is it somehow reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to_s` simply converts the numbers (20, 0, etc.) to strings ("20", "0", etc.). So it's identical to this:

```
if Rails.cache
  Rails.cache.fetch("20") # ec2-50-17-225-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
  Rails.cache.fetch("0")  # ec2-174-129-33-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
  Rails.cache.fetch("10") # ec2-174-129-16-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
  Rails.cache.fetch("30") # ec2-54-242-2-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11212
end
```

So somewhere, these amazonaws URLs are being stored in the cache using the keys "20", "0", etc., and then the code above retrieves those values from the cache.

(Depending on the cache store being used, e.g. with ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore or Dalli, you can just use the integer value without converting to a string first, so the `to_s` might be unnecessary).